# Class returning a (private?) range

Tags: vba, class, range

I wondering if I'm going about this wrong. I'm starting to get into classes and trying to use them more in my VBA code.

I created a code which imports a CSV file to a newly created worksheet. 
I create the worksheet within the class and import to the file to some range.
The range will vary depending on the file being imported. 
Ideally I'd like to return the range reference to my module outside of the class and cycle through the range as I would need.

I can't seem to sucsucessly return a range object with my module code. 
with:

```
' Module code '''' \/
set NewTest as new TestClass
Dim testrange As Range
test Range = NewTest.SourceRange
' Module code '''' /\




Option Explicit

Const cDirectory As String = "C:\directory" 'file path
Const cFileExt As String = ".CSV" 'file

Const cSourceCode As String = "wsSourceCode"


Private cFinalFileName As String
Private wsSourceCode As Worksheet
Private cSourcePath As String
Private pSourceRange As Range
Private LastRow As Integer
Private pSourceSheet As String


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' Can i do this !?!?!?!? \/
Public Property Get SourceRange() As Range
    LastRow = wsSourceCode.Cells(wsSourceCode.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set pSourceRange = wsSourceCode.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    SourceRange = pSourceRange
End Property
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' Can i do this !?!?!?!? ?|



Public Property Get SourceSheet() As String
    pSourceSheet = wsSourceCode.Name
    SourceSheet = pSourceSheet
End Property




Public Property Get FinalRange() As String
    FinalRange = pFinalRange
End Property

Public Property Set FinalRange(Value As Range)
    pFinalRange = Value
End Property

Public Property Let SourceFile(Value As String)
    pSourceFile = Value
    cFinalFileName = pSourceFile & "Production" & cFileExt
    cSourcePath = cDirectory & pSourceFile & cFileExt
End Property



Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    'Create Holding Sheet to Populate and augment Code
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSourceCode).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = cSourceCode
    Set wsSourceCode = Sheets(cSourceCode)
    'WsHolding.Visible = False
End Sub


Private Sub Class_Terminate()
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'    On Error Resume Next
'    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cSourceCode).Delete
'    On Error GoTo 0
'    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub



Public Sub ExportCode(ByVal pFinalRange As Range)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'This Process Will import the final Range of output
'code and export it to a Output file.
' The Output file was delare earlier.
'
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim fso As Object
Dim Fileout As Object
Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
myFile = cOutputFile
Open myFile For Output As #1
For Each rng In pFinalRange
    Print #1, rng
Next rng
Close 1

End Sub


Public Sub ImportFile(ByVal cSourceFileName As String)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'This Process Will import the final Range of output
'code and export it to a Output file.
' The Output file was delare earlier.
'
'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim cSourcePath As String
cSourcePath = cDirectory & cSourceFileName & cFileExt
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Dim i As Integer: i = 1
Open cSourcePath For Input As #iFile 'open the file
Do Until EOF(1) 'until the end of the file
    Line Input #1, strTextLine 'set each line equal to variable strTextLine
    wsSourceCode.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
    wsSourceCode.Cells(i, 1) = CStr(strTextLine)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #iFile



End Sub
```

Comment: A `Range` is an object, so you need to use the `Set` keyword everywhere you assign it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is basically [what @Comintern said.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413231/class-returning-a-private-range#comment66150774_39413231)

This:

> ```
> SourceRange = pSourceRange
> ```

Should be this:

```
Set SourceRange = pSourceRange
```

I ran the latest [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s *code inspections* on your class, and my little ducky (I manage that open-source project) agrees:

> **Object variable 'SourceRange' is assigned without the 'Set' keyword**
>
> As far as Rubberduck can tell, this variable is an object variable, assigned without the 'Set' keyword. This causes run-time error 91 'Object or With block variable not set'.

So you ask, *can I do this?*

Sure, you *can* - the real question is whether you *should*.

You have a `Property Get` procedure *that has side-effects* and that *can raise a runtime error* if the stars are aligned. That's not good.

A `Property Get` procedure should have predictable and reproducible behavior - it shouldn't be *setting* anything in the class' internal state, rather be *returning* a value that's encapsulated in that internal, private state.

Take a moment to read the [.net property design guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx) - all of it is *also* applicable to VBA property design (just replace "throwing exceptions" with "raising errors").

So a *better* `SourceRange` property would look something like this:

```
Public Property Get SourceRange() As Range
    If wsSourceCode Is Nothing Then Exit Property
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = = wsSourceCode.Cells(wsSourceCode.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set SourceRange = wsSourceCode.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
End Property
```

Note that the readonly (get-only) property stands on its own, scopes its own local variables, doesn't mutate internal state, returns `Nothing` if the `wsSourceCode` reference isn't set, and doesn't assume the worksheet has less than 32,767 rows (that's the maximum value for an `Integer` variable).

What doesn't *need* to live at module level, should live at procedure level: keep variable scopes as small as possible.

---

If this were a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) answer I'd also say that the `Class_Initialize` handler is doing way too many, not easily predictable things<sup>1</sup> - consider this use case; how are `foo` and `bar` any different?

```
Set foo = New TestClass
Set bar = New TestClass

'this goes boom. why?
Debug.Print foo.SourceRange.Address, bar.SourceRange.Address
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Oops, well I said it anyway.</sub>